# text manipulation with powershell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-distributed-file-system, netapp

I'm trying to format the output of this command to get only the dfsnamespace only like that :

```
\\F-TYPHON\DATA13\AI-Project
```

I can not use the `Get-DfsnFolderTarget` cmdlet because the `RSAT-DFS-Mgmt-Con`
is not installed on all servers and I cannot install it .

```
$DFSPath="\\F-TYPHON\shared\AI-Project"

PS C:\> dfsutil client property state $DFSPath

Active, Online      \\F-TYPHON\DATA13\AI-Project

Done processing this command.
```

I've tried this .

```
PS C:\> $dfs=dfsutil client property state $DFSPath

PS C:\> $dfs.trimstart("Active, Online")
```

> Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'trimstart'.
>   At line:1 char:15
>   + $dfs.trimstart <<<< ("Active, Online")
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (trimstart:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

any help will be apreciated I can list all volume data for the filer but there's many incoherence in the structure so I need only to list the shared folder under "shared" on a filer and then procces it with dfsutil to get the absolut path

Comment: try doing `$dfs.GetType()` and `$dfs | Select-Object -Property *` so that you can see what is in the $Var ... and then choose the correct prop to use. [*grin*] i suspect you are looking at an array of strings instead of one long, multiline string.

Comment: PS C:\> $dfs.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
here the output for the first

Comment: PS C:\> $dfs | Select-Object -Property *
                                                                                                 Length
                                                                                                       ------
                                                                                                            0
                                                                                                          29
                                                                                                                     47

Comment: so it is a _string array_, not a _string_. [*grin*] take a look at `Select-String` for ways to deal with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression to match the text output of dfsutil:

```
$DFSPath="\\F-TYPHON\shared\AI-Project"

if ((dfsutil client property state $DFSPath) -match "(?<=\s{2,})\\\\.*"){
   $DFSNameSpace = $Matches.Value
}
```

- here `(?<=\s{2,})\\\\.*` matches two or more whitespace `\s` in a [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
  followed by two (escaped) backslashes and the remainder of the line.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help 
i've found a solution that i can use in a way it's not 100% powershell but i can use it to extract the output in a format that i can use it in a loop and than make automated robocopylines with powershell

here the code for the output that i found

$DFSPath="\F-TYPHON\shared\AI-Project"

$dfspath=(dfsutil client property state $DFSPath |findstr /i \F-TYPHON)|out-string

$dfs=$dfspath.Trimstart("Active, Online     ")

write-host $dfs
the output is

\F-TYPHON\DATA13\AI-Project

it's certainly not the best but i can work with it

if you have any others suggestion you're welcome